# Jquery Ui Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have used the following link to create a accordion for a website, but I would like to change few to it, tried all over the net couldn't find the solution.

I want to change when we add a new accordion close the accordion if any open. Also when added the first accordion always opens which I think I have solved some what.

you can find the demo under the following link,

```
 [link] http://jsfiddle.net/gnhkm4es/
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Updated [link] http://jsfiddle.net/kpnjrq11/1/

Comment: You fiddle does not work..

Comment: new link http://jsfiddle.net/gnhkm4es/

Comment: I have upated the new link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( ".questions" ).accordion({
        header: "> div > h3",
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,             // this can be changed to 0 for first accordion opened
        autoHeight: false,
        autoActivate: true
    });

    $( "button" ).button();
    $('#addAccordion').click( function() {
        var newDiv = "<div><h3>Q4 New Question</h3><div>New Content</div></div>";
        $('.questions').append(newDiv)
        $('.questions').accordion("refresh").accordion( "option", "active", $('.questions > div').length - 1 );
    });
});
```

Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/gnhkm4es/1/) is

Comment: @ AmanVirdi it is clearly mentioned that `when we add a new accordion close the accordion if any open` ...

Comment: @IIIusion, Please check the Fiddle, It closes the already opened and open the newly added, And I think this what mentioned in the question.

Comment: `when we add a new accordion close the accordion if any open`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  $('.questions').accordion({active:false});  after  $('.questions').accordion("refresh");

http://jsfiddle.net/gnhkm4es/10/

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $( ".questions" ).accordion({
        header: "> div > h3",
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        autoHeight: false,
        autoActivate: true
    });

    $( "button" ).button();
    $('#addAccordion').click( function() {
        var newDiv = "<div><h3>Q4 New Question</h3><div>New Content</div></div>";
        $('.questions').append(newDiv)
        $('.questions').accordion("refresh"); 
        $('.questions').accordion({active:false}); 
    });
});
```

if you want to open the last panel in the accordion replace false with -1
    $('.questions').accordion({active:-1}); 
refer accordion documentation under active
http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/